# Please find attached the document consisting of code

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Which one of the following is correct -

Please find attached the document consisting of code.
Please find the attached document consisting of code.
Please find attached the file consisting of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of this is actually grammatically incorrect. None of them feels quite natural. I have occasion to send files of code with some frequency, and I would not write any of these in a business (or personal) email. I would be inclined to write:

> - Please find attached a file containing code.
> - Attached is a file containing code.
> - Attached is a file with the code. (Assuming other context had identified the code specifically.)
> - Please find attached a file containing the code. (Same assumption.)

The word "document" could be used in place of "file" in any of the above sentences, that is a matter of style. "Consisting of" seems wordy, but is not incorrect.